# mrepo and grouplist/groupinstall?, mrepo not working as expected with group

Tags: redhat, yum, groups, rpm

All,

I'm trying to set up **mrepo** so we can have internal repositories. After quite the slog, things seem to be working as expected *EXCEPT* for groups.

From `man createrepo`:

> EXAMPLES Here is an example of a repository with a groups file. Note
>   that the groups file should be in the same directory as the rpm
>   packages (i.e. /path/to/rpms/comps.xml).
>
> createrepo -g comps.xml /path/to/rpms

---

So here's what I'm doing:

```
wget -c http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6/x86_64/os/repodata/comps-sl6-x86_64.xml
cp comps-sl6-x86_64.xml /var/mrepo/SL6-x86_64/os/Packages/comps-sl6-x86_64.xml
createrepo -g comps-sl6-x86_64.xml /var/mrepo/SL6-x86_64/os/Packages/
```

**lots of output, no apparent errors or warnings**

BUT.. from a client:

```
yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Group Process
Error: No group data available for configured repositories
```

Here's `/etc/mrepo.conf`:

```
### Configuration file for mrepo
### The [main] section allows to override mrepo's default settings
### The mrepo-example.conf gives an overview of all the possible settings
[main]
srcdir = /var/mrepo
wwwdir = /var/www/mrepo
confdir = /etc/mrepo.conf.d
arch = x86_64
mailto = root@localhost
smtp-server = localhost
pxelinux = /usr/lib/syslinux/pxelinux.0
tftpdir = /tftpboot
#rhnlogin = username:password

### Any other section is considered a definition for a distribution
### You can put distribution sections in /etc/mrepo.conf.d
### Examples can be found in the documentation.
```

Here's `/etc/mrepo.conf.d/sl6.mrepo`:

```
### Scientific Linux 6
[SL6]
name = Scientific Linux 6
release = 6
arch = x86_64
metadata = repomd repoview
os = rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/$release/$arch/os/
updates = rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/$release/$arch/updates/
security = rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/$release/$arch/updates/security/
fastbugs = rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/$release/$arch/updates/fastbugs/
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late answer.  Hopefully this helps you or some one else searching this topic.

I'd really like to see that output that you've indicated does not appear to contain any errors.  However, one thing missing from your post is the option `-d`.  In my man page this is indicated to **generate sqlite databases for use with yum.**  I'm not sure that `createrepo` is doing much without this option.  Maybe it's indexing the directory, but not generating any output.

This is what I use and it works quite well:

```
createrepo -g /path/to/comps.xml -pd --update /path/to/RPMs
```

Cheers.

Comment: I actually had to move on from this issue, so it's still out there hanging.  I'll have to go back and revisit this when I can.  Hope it's as simple as the '-d' !  That would be cool.

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this?